# Android and Java win 10 compatibility

Tags: compatibility

I would like to learn android using android studio. But I do not know which java sdk, android sdk and android studio are win 10 compatible? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro
You don't have to worry about compatibility as Windows 10 is the latest and latest version of Android Studio is compatible with it.

The latest version of Android Studio is 3.5 at the time of writing this.